# Both swipe from left and swipe from right navigation in the same app; is it a good choice?

Tags: interaction-design, menu, tablet, swipe

I'm designing the interaction and UI for a RWD e-commerce page.

On tablet and mobile front page there has to be a hidden place for:

1. list of categories
2. shopping card
3. login/register + open shop panel

There is an idea to place those in swipe=panels, but on both sides. There is one more problem, that these are 3 and we have only 2 sides to swipe....

On the mockup you can see:

1. the left-hand side with categories (you can open it with hamburger or swipe right)

[image]

2. the right-hand side with shopping card ( open by click on bascet, no swipe)

[image]

3. ALSO  the right-hand side with login/register panel ( open with left hand swipe, or by click on "unlogged in" avatar)

[image]

So as you can see I have doubts if a user could identify the left swipe only with avatar (login/ and after all profile options) and not with the basket icon = the shopping card view?

What do you recommend: should I create something else for mobile? Or for mobile and tablet should I use just one left-hand swipe (as it is in the mobile app of StackExchange for example? :) )

Please recognise on the screens the place of arrows " > "  and " < "
should I align them to right-hand side on both sides? Or should it be in the same place as the hamburger?

Here is the link to interactive mockup: http://invis.io/291P0H5A8

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can implement handles or some sort of indicator for the swiping actions I would leave them out.

Interactions with the slider content will also get confusing.

In my head you should have the off canvas menus dedicated to one thing:

- left one for menu items
- right one for shopping cart

The login/register feels like it should be a modal or something similar.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @David. At the moment, this post reads as a list of opinions ("get confusing"..."in my head"..."feels like") .  Is there any evidence (such as citation of a study or a reference to a UI pattern or design principle) that you could use to support those opinions?